# How can I make this api call correctly and get the news from the api using fetch

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

Note: the api Key is fake for privacy.

```
const url = 'http://newsapi.org/v2/everything?' +
          'q=platformer&' +
          'apiKey=3ce15c4d1fd3485cbcf17879bab498db';

async function getNews() {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
}

getNews()
```

The problem is that when I run this javascript code I get this error:

***Access to fetch at 'http://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=platformer&apiKey=3ce15c4d1fd3485cbcf17879bab498db' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.***

Basically I want to pull news from this newsapi.org and and see the data in the console.

Comment: Because of the website's CORS policy, you cannot fetch data from a different domain. A solution would be to use axios in Node.js

Comment: Making the requests on the server-side would be better, indeed. Because your API key is private. It should not be shared with anyone, so not embedded in your front-end code. That's the reason why the API did not enable CORS. [Docs](https://newsapi.org/docs/authentication)  _"You can attach your API key to a request in one of three ways: - apiKey querystring parameter. - X-Api-Key HTTP header. - Authorization HTTP header. **We strongly recommend either of the latter 2 so that your API key isn't visible to others** in logs or request sniffing."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message of [News API](https://newsapi.org/) provides a hint:

> *Requests from the browser are not allowed on the Developer plan, except from localhost*

Assuming that you are indeed running the app using a local development server (like [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)), pointing your browser to `http://localhost:8080/` instead of `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` does the trick:

[image: Successful News Api fetch from localhost]

Code sample below (run locally with a webserver):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>News</h1>

  <button id="btn-get">Get News</button>
  <div id="news-container"></div>
  <script>
    const url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=bitcoin&apiKey=API_KEY`

    const newsContainer = document.getElementById('news-container')

    function fetchNews(url) {
      return fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
    }

    document.getElementById('btn-get').addEventListener('click', () => {
      fetchNews(url)
        .then(articles => newsContainer.textContent = JSON.stringify(articles))
    })

  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this does work when I'm running on localhost but my website is hosted on university.edu

Answer (score 1):

In short, you can utilize a **CORS Proxy**.

Your question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43881141/7902641), which provides a larger CORS Proxy explanation and walkthrough.

---

There's also an accepted answer for **NewsApi.org** specifically that's a bit more brief [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61951830/7902641).

**Excerpt:**

> You need a CORS proxy
>
> ```
> const proxyUrl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/"
> const qInTitle = "";
> const from = "";
> const apiKey = "";
> const url = `${proxyUrl}https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?qInTitle=${qInTitle}&from=${from}language=en&apiKey=${apiKey}`;
> const request = new Request(url);
>
> fetch(request)
>   .then(response => response.json())
>   .then((news) => {
>     console.log(news);
>   })
>   .catch(error => {
>     console.log(error);
>   });
> ```

---

Also, here's a pretty thorough article if you need to know more about CORS in general:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: As a comment above suggests, it would be bad practice to expose their API key to a service which should be kept private.

Comment: @Bren That may be true (and I definitely agree with @blex!), but if the OP is not asking for best practice, providing answers on utilizing a CORS proxy or other viable workarounds may still prove to be helpful for whatever the OP's objective is.

Comment: Im getting a 426 upgrade error: newsapi.js:20 GET https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?qInTitle=platformer&from=uslanguage=en&apiKey=3ce15c4d1fd3485cbcf17879bab498db 426 (Upgrade Required)